# extracting data from facebook using graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, social-media

how can i extract name list && phone numbers of the users liking certain page ?
I have tried using software called facepager but i couldn't extract names .
note:I'm not the owner of the page

Comment: you can`t, because it is not allowed to scrape facebook. data of users who did not specifically authorize your app to do so is none of your business, especially when you do not even own the page in question. it is not even possible to get the phone of users with any permission, for very good reasons. what would you do with the phone number anyway? you do know about data privacy, right?

Answer (score 0):

You'd most likely have to write code yourself to do something like this. However,

- Almost no-one publicly shares their phone number.
- Facebook try to prevent this kind of data collection.

Even when facebook list's "likers" of a page, it'll wait till you scroll down to load more. You'd have to play with your browsers debug tools and look into where it get's that data from

```
https://www.facebook.com/search/<group id here>/likers
```

In the end you'll probably not get much better than just searching for the page and clicking each person's profile because the site is designed to not let what you're trying to do happen...